# Unable to authenticate my AWS credentials for ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I have installed the latest versions of the aws-cli-2 and docker, as well as ran "aws configure" and entered my access key and secret key. I have also verified the aws.config is correct and showing the right region and output format. My credentials in AWS are admin. I keep getting the following error:

'''Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device'''

Even though I have already ran 'aws configure.' I am running the commands prefixed with 'sudo' as well. Any thoughts?! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you run the `aws configure` using sudo too?

Comment: That was the fix! I must need more coffee this morning, can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you!

Comment: Added answer. Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 15):

The `aws configure` command was being run as the local user, whereas the ecr command was being run as sudo.

If you run commands as sudo it will not have access to your local users config, it will instead default to the root users.

Instead ensure all commands are run as the same user.

If you want to use the aws credentials file from the default location you can also specify the location via the `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable.

Comment: and if you're trying to run as sudo because you got a permission denied error from Docker Daemon, running this might fix it: `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Both relevant and useful answers, thank you

Answer (score 1):

run -----> sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock in ubuntu

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).